# How to add a space into checkBoxGroup label?

Tags: xpages

Here is checkBox group

```
<xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup1" layout="pageDirection">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="aaaaa"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="bbbbb"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="ccccc"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="ddd       fgggggg"></xp:selectItem>
</xp:checkBoxGroup></xp:view>
```

the space in fourth item label is ignored. Adding space escape `&nbsp;` ingored as well

Comment: Try Knut's answer but encode the ampersand (&) like this - &amp;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use non-breaking space `&#160;`.

Add as many non-breaking spaces as you like

```
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="ddd&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;fgggggg"></xp:selectItem>
```

Comment: well it adds spaces when you see this control in Designer. But on xPage itself it doesn't

Comment: It shows spaces in browser too. I tested it with Domino 9.0.1.

Comment: Thank you Knut.. I'll test it on 9.0.1.. Now I'm just using Domino and Client 8.5

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap, this below looks like:[image: In Line checkboxes with margin-right]

```
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">

                    <xp:checkBox id="labelPCL" text="PCLx" value="px" style="margin-right:7px;"></xp:checkBox>

                    <xp:checkBox id="labelHAL" text="HALx" value="hx" style="margin-right:7px;margin-left:10px;"></xp:checkBox>

                    <xp:checkBox id="checkBox6" text="SBNx" value="sx" style="margin-right:7px;margin-left:10px;"></xp:checkBox>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is what the same looks like without the style:margin-right/left added: [image: Checkboxes No Style _ no good]